# how to implement gridview on fragment correctly

Tags: android, eclipse, gridview, fragment

how do i correctly implement this code on my app? i think the current source code that i have now has double same code. the source code is located below which is this one public void onItemClick(AdapterView arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3)

`

```
private GridView photoGrid;
private int mPhotoSize, mPhotoSpacing;
private ImageAdapter imageAdapter;

// Some items to add to the GRID
private static final String[] CONTENT = new String[] { "Pregnancy Stages", "Complications", "Diet And Fitness", "Myths And Facts",
    "Helplines", "FAQ's" };private static final int[] ICONS = new int[] { R.drawable.babygrid4, R.drawable.babygrid5,
    R.drawable.babygrid3, R.drawable.babygrid1, R.drawable.babygrid2, R.drawable.babygrid6, };

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, container, false);


    // get the photo size and spacing
    mPhotoSize = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.photo_size);
    mPhotoSpacing = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.photo_spacing);

    // initialize image adapter
    imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter();

    photoGrid = (GridView) getView().findViewById(R.id.albumGrid);
    photoGrid.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    GridView gridview = (GridView) getView().findViewById (R.id.albumGrid);
        gridview.setAdapter (new ImageAdapter()); 

        gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
        {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Intent myIntent = null;
                if(position == 0){
                    myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), PregnancyStagesMainActivity.class);
                }
                if(position == 1){
                    myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), ComplicationsMainActivity.class);
                }
                if(position == 2){
                    myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), DietAndFitnessMainActivity.class);
                }
                if(position == 3){
                    myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), MythsAndFactsMainActivity.class);
                }
                if(position == 4){
                    myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), HelplinesMainActivity.class);
                }
                if(position == 5){
                    myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), FaqsMainActivity.class);
                }
                startActivity(myIntent);
            }
        });


    // set image adapter to the GridView
    photoGrid.setAdapter(imageAdapter);

    // Set the Required Animation to GridView and start the Animation
    // use fly_in_from_center to have 2nd type of animation effect (snapshot 2)
    Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.anim.in_from_left);
    gridview.setAnimation(anim);
    anim.start();

    // get the view tree observer of the grid and set the height and numcols dynamically
    photoGrid.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            if (imageAdapter.getNumColumns() == 0) {
                final int numColumns = (int) Math.floor(photoGrid.getWidth() / (mPhotoSize + mPhotoSpacing));
                if (numColumns > 0) {
                    final int columnWidth = (photoGrid.getWidth() / numColumns) - mPhotoSpacing;
                    imageAdapter.setNumColumns(numColumns);
                    imageAdapter.setItemHeight(columnWidth);

                }
            }
        }
    });
}

// ///////// ImageAdapter class /////////////////
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private int mItemHeight = 0;
    private int mNumColumns = 0;
    private RelativeLayout.LayoutParams mImageViewLayoutParams;

    public ImageAdapter() {
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        mImageViewLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return CONTENT.length;
    }

    // set numcols
    public void setNumColumns(int numColumns) {
        mNumColumns = numColumns;
    }

    public int getNumColumns() {
        return mNumColumns;
    }

    // set photo item height
    public void setItemHeight(int height) {
        if (height == mItemHeight) {
            return;
        }
        mItemHeight = height;
        mImageViewLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, mItemHeight);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (view == null)
            view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.photo_item, null);

        ImageView cover = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.cover);
        TextView title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);

        cover.setLayoutParams(mImageViewLayoutParams);

        // Check the height matches our calculated column width
        if (cover.getLayoutParams().height != mItemHeight) {
            cover.setLayoutParams(mImageViewLayoutParams);
        }

        cover.setImageResource(ICONS[position % ICONS.length]);
        title.setText(CONTENT[position % CONTENT.length]);

        return view;
    }
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}


}
```

`

Comment: Could you clarify what your goal is here?  It looks like you are using the child `View`s of the `GridView` to start new `Activity`s - is this strictly what you are asking to do?  It also looks like you make a call to `setOnItemClickListener()`, and pass in `this` as a parameter, but it seems like there is no implementation of the method.  Perhaps this is the issue?

Comment: actually i wanted to implement a gridview on a tab fragment. what is child view? i'm quite new to all this stuff.

Comment: Anyone? I really dont know how to go on from here.